# Should I cite TikZ code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibliographies, citing

In my thesis, I use several TikZ plots, and I usually moderately modify the codes I found from the internet to generate those plots. 
Thus, should I give citations to those codes?

Comment: as you wish, as a token of gratitude

Comment: I suppose this depends on the license on the code you've copied and modified, but personally I would put down some form of acknowledgement. In my thesis, for instance, I thanked _Tex StackExchange_ for all the help I got in producing my report. But I wouldn't go as far as putting the source of the TikZ code as a reference.

Comment: There are three potential issues. One has to do with plagiarism and another with intellectual property. The last has to do with courtesy. For the first, you should ask your advisor. I highly doubt not citing the sources would be considered plagiarism, but these things can be very context and discipline specific. For the second, it would depend on the licence, as @gablin mentioned. For the last, I'd also recommend acknowledging the help you had in producing the thesis. I acknowledged the maths department and, I think, AMS for help re. the class in mine. I didn't cite them, though.

Comment: I should *blame* TeX and friends for making me extremely paranoid on kerning, alignment and whatnot. I am beginning to think that's *one strong reason* my thesis is taking so long... `:)`

Comment: @cfr: This scenario reminds me of this video by John Cleese: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_JUBgPHYmY (emphasis on the The Royal Society for the Prevention of Birds). `:)`

Comment: @gablin if the code came from stackexchange then in the absence of a statement from the author specifying a different licence, it is available in the licence given on every page which is *user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required. *

Comment: Some time ago a number of TeX.SE regulars have stated their preference (attribution or not) in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/relicensing-code-from-answers

Comment: @PauloCereda Na. That's TeX SE. You can happily use TeX for a thesis in blissful ignorance.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm afraid that the idea of watching a video on this machine is the definition of a conceptual impossibility. Not a chance. It won't even open the page I need to download the software I need to get another machine running. Pah.

Comment: @cfr video? Oh you meant to ping Paulo:-)

Comment: @PauloCereda: Considering I've asked over a hundred questions here, most of which are in relation to writing either my Master thesis or PhD thesis, that's pretty much how my acknowledgement section would look like.

Comment: @gablin: I can relate to that too. `:)`

Comment: @gablin I didn't mentione members of the maths department by name. Possibly I ought to have, but then I'd have been sure to have left somebody out and I don't know if I remembered all the names. I'm pretty sure I just clumped them: maths department + AMS. Probably, in all fairness, I should have acknowledged the role yeast played, too. (Making bread often gets me unstuck.) But I probably thought the maths stuff looked pretty weird already.